# Asymptotic of an Integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, bessel-functions

I have the following problem. Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I(\tau, \xi)=\frac{\xi}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dz\frac{\exp(-i\tau\cosh{z}/\xi)}{\cosh^{3}{z}}, \quad \tau, \xi>0 .
\end{align}
This integral extremely looks like one of those know representation of Bessel/modified Bessel/Hankel functions or their combinations, however I was not able to find this particular one anywhere, so do it numerically. The only analytical insight I was intended to obtain is the asymptotic behaviour of the integral for $\tau\gg\xi$. For this sake we rewrite it as
\begin{align}
I(\tau, \xi)&=\frac{\xi}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dz\frac{\exp(-i\tau\cosh{z}/\xi)}{\cosh^{3}{z}}=\frac{\xi}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}dz\frac{\exp(-i\tau\cosh{z}/\xi)}{\cosh^{3}{z}}\\
&=\frac{\xi}{2\pi}\int_{1}^{\infty}dw\frac{\exp(-i\tau w/\xi)}{w^{3}\sqrt{w^{2}-1}}.
\end{align}
The integrand has a branch pole at $w=1$ on the integration contour. In order to analyse $\tau\gg\xi$ behaviour it is beneficial to analytically continue the square root into the lower half plane
\begin{align}
\sqrt{w^{2}-1}\rightarrow i\sqrt{-i(w+1)}\sqrt{-i(w-1)}.
\end{align}
Note that this indeed gives the disired result since $\sqrt{w^{2}-1}=i\sqrt{-i(w+1)}\sqrt{-i(w-1)}, \  w\in\mathbb{R}$ and the root has now the jump across the line $w=1-iy, \quad y\in\mathbb{R}$.  In prticular, for $w=1-iy\pm\eta, \quad y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align}
 i\sqrt{-i2-y}\sqrt{-y\mp i\eta}&=\pm i\sqrt{i2+y}\sqrt{y}\simeq \pm i(1+i)\sqrt{y}, \quad y\ll1,\\
(1-iy)^{3}&\simeq 1, \quad y\ll1.
\end{align}
It follows
\begin{align}
I(\tau, \xi)&\simeq-\underbrace{(-1)}_{\text{lower half}}\frac{\xi}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{e^{-i(1-iy)v_{F}t/\xi}}{(1+i)\sqrt{y}}=\xi e^{-i(\tau/\xi+\pi/4)}\sqrt{\frac{\xi}{2\pi\tau}}, \quad \tau\gg\xi.
\end{align}
The thing is that this asymptotic does not agree with numerics unless it is multiplied by an extra factor of $1/2$. I.e.
\begin{align}
\frac{\xi}{2} e^{-i(\tau/\xi+\pi/4)}\sqrt{\frac{\xi}{2\pi\tau}}, \quad \tau\gg\xi,
\end{align}
approximates $I(\tau, \xi)$ perfectly for large $\tau/xi$....

Can anyone hint me where my mistake is? I mean factors of 1/2 from perfect agreement is clearly not an accident. Sorry in case the question is stupid in a way that it is based on my lack of elementary knowledge, or so, I'm just a physicist =)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how the factor of $2$ disappeared from the denominator in the formula with $v_F t$ (I assume $v_F t$ is $\tau$). We have
$$\int_0^\infty
 \frac {e^{-i A w}} {(w + 1)^3 \sqrt w \sqrt {w + 2}} dw =
\int_0^{-i \infty}
 \frac {e^{-i A w}} {(w + 1)^3 \sqrt w \sqrt {w + 2}} dw \sim
\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \int_0^{-i \infty} \frac {e^{-i A w}} {\sqrt w} dw$$
(with the principal value of the square root) for $A \to \infty$, which gives the desired asymptotics.